# QChart z-values not respected when using openGL acceleration?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qtopengl, qtcharts

I'm trying to do something almost exactly the same as the Qt5 [callout example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-callout-example.html), but I've discovered that if you call `setUseOpenGL(true)` on the series, then the callout appears *under* the line instead of above it.

This is true no matter what `zValue` is set to, including `m_tooltip->setZValue(std::numeric_limits<qreal>::max());`

Is there a workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: Have you ever found a workaround for this problem?

Comment: no, just disabling opengl acceleration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because OpenGL accelerated series works by creating an [QOpenGLWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) on top of the actual QGraphicsView, as noted in the documentation of the [useOpenGL property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractseries.html#useOpenGL-prop):

> If you draw any graphics items on top of a chart containing an accelerated series, the accelerated series is drawn over those items.

Basically, as the Callout is rendered inside the QGraphicsView, when OpenGL is enabled a QOpenGLWidget is created on top of that QGraphicsView and because that the callout appears below the line.